# Intersection of Two Map rdd's in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDD's, for example:
firstmapRDD - (0-14,List(0, 4, 19, 19079, 42697, 444, 42748))

secondmapRdd-(0-14,List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94))

I want to find the intersection. 
I tried, var interResult = firstmapRDD.intersection(secondmapRdd), which shows no result in output file.
I also tried , cogrouping based on keys, mapRDD.cogroup(secondMapRDD).filter(x=>), but I don't know how to find the intersection between both the values, is it x=>x._1.intersect(x._2), Can someone help me with the syntax?
Even this throws a compile time error, mapRDD.cogroup(secondMapRDD).filter(x=>x._1.intersect(x._2))

```
 var mapRDD = sc.parallelize(map.toList)
 var secondMapRDD = sc.parallelize(secondMap.toList)
 var interResult = mapRDD.intersection(secondMapRDD)
```

It may be because of ArrayBuffer[List[]] values, because of which the intersection is not working. Is there any hack to remove it?

I tried doing this

```
var interResult = mapRDD.cogroup(secondMapRDD).filter{case (_, (l,r))    => l.nonEmpty && r.nonEmpty }. map{case (k,(l,r)) => (k, l.toList.intersect(r.toList))}
```

Still getting an empty list!

Comment: Types are String, List[String]

Comment: Output expected is : 0-14-> 4,19

Comment: Initially I have a map of List[String] then I parallelize into mapRDD using  var secondMapRDD = sc.parallelize(secondMap.toList)

Comment: @user3663622 : if your rdd is pairrdd, then you can use intersect, it should work fine.

Comment: @Shankar, no intersection gives no result. in output file, var interResult = firstmapRDD.intersection(secondmapRdd), both are map rdd's, the structure is give above.

Comment: @user3663622 : add your code how you are creating rdd, so its easy to answer.

Comment: @Shankar , am actually converting scala map of type [String, List[String]] to     rdd, am getting the results in map rdd's , but not able to get the intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking `intersect on values`, you need to `join` both RDDs, get all the matched values, then do the intersect on values.

**sample code:**

```
val firstMap = Map(1 -> List(1,2,3,4,5))
  val secondMap = Map(1 -> List(1,2,5))

  val firstKeyRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(firstMap.toList, 2)
  val secondKeyRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(secondMap.toList, 2)

  val joinedRDD = firstKeyRDD.join(secondKeyRDD)
  val finalResult = joinedRDD.map(tuple => {
    val matchedLists = tuple._2
    val intersectValues = matchedLists._1.intersect(matchedLists._2)
    (tuple._1, intersectValues)
  })

  finalResult.foreach(println)
```

**The output will be**

```
(1,List(1, 2, 5))
```